# В чем разница между @,=,& при получении значений атрибута в directive ? Angular

Tags: angularjs

Вот простой рабочий пример получения значение атрибутов с элемента

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController">

<div my-directive
     my-url="http://google.com"
     my-link-text="Click me">

     </div>

</div>

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myUrl: '@',
      myLinkText: '@'
    },
    template: '<a href="{{myUrl}}">{{myLinkText}}</a>'
  };
});
```

Но я встретил конструкцию следующего вида

```
scope: {
            text: "@myText",
            twoWayBind: "=myTwoWayBind",
            oneWayBind: "&myOneWayBind"
        }
```

Подскажите что ознают = и & ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What is the difference between & vs @ and = in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)